# Django url variable catching

Tags: python, django, web

I'm having trouble at having Django `urlpatterns` catch a variable as an variable and instead take it as a set URL.

urlpatterns:

```
    urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^about/', views.about),
    url(r'^views/available_products/',  views.available_products),
    url(r'^views/productview/<int:product_id>/', views.productview)
]
```

When I host the server and go to /about/, /views/available_products/ or /admin/ they work fine, but trying to go to /views/productview/1/ gives a 404 error whereas going to /views/productview// gives a missing argument -error.

I tried to read the documentation and saw no obvious tell as to why my url variable argument wouldn't work, but clearly I'm doing something fundamentally wrong.

Here is an example error message from the debug page:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/views/productview/12/
Using the URLconf defined in firstdjango.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^admin/
^about/
^views/available_products/
^views/productview/<int:product_id>/
The current path, views/productview/12/, didn't match any of these.
```

And here is the same error message but where the URL I try with is the same as in urlpatterns:

```
TypeError at /views/productview/<int:product_id>/
productview() missing 1 required positional argument: 'product_id'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/views/productview/%3Cint:product_id%3E/
Django Version: 1.11.8
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
productview() missing 1 required positional argument: 'product_id'
Server time:    Sat, 10 Feb 2018 12:25:21 +0000
```

views.py:

```
    from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404
from django.shortcuts import render

def starting_instructions(request):
    return render(request, "webshop/instructions.html", {})

def about(request):
    return HttpResponse("about page")

def productview(request, product_id):
    """
    Write your view implementations for exercise 4 here.
    Remove the current return line below.
    """
    return HttpResponse("product {}".format(product_id))

def available_products(request):
    """
    Write your view implementations for exercise 4 here.
    Remove the current return line below.
    """
    return HttpResponse("View not implemented!")
```

Comment: Paste here please the `views.py` containing the  `productview` view. Do you have any `get_object_or_404(...)` in it?

Comment: Added views.py now and as far as I can tell, no, it seems like it's genuinely just not catching the int as an arg for the 4th urlpattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This url is not translated correctly.

see `Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/views/productview/%3Cint:product_id%3E/`

You can use eighter `path` or `re_path` (which is similar to url and you can use regex in it so as you can use in url). So change your urlpatterns to.

```
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('about/', views.about),
    path('views/available_products/',  views.available_products),
    path('views/productview/<int:product_id>/', views.productview)
]
```

**EDIT**

or if you really want to use url, use it like

```
url('^views/productview/(?P<product_id>\d+)/$', views.productview)
```

But using `path` is the Django 2.0+ approach. Also replacing  `url` with `re_path` which is the same.

Comment: Is there no way to use variable argument with `url`? I was given the first urlpattern from the beginning, so it would be quite deceiving to not be able to use it in the first place. Accepting the answer anyway if I get it to work with this, give me a second to try it out

Comment: @Grak You can use the regex pattern to use it with `url` as `url('^views/productview/(?P<product_id>\d+)/$', views.productview)`

Comment: This works! Thanks. I was trying to look for url() specific documentation because I found it odd that I was only able to find path() but I brushed it off in ignorance. Is url() simply outdated ?

Comment: @Grak As I know, I could say yes. Using `url` instead of `re_path` gives you no advantage and it could be deprecated to use in newer versions of Django.

Comment: From Django documentation:

`This function is an alias to django.urls.re_path(). It’s likely to be deprecated in a future release.`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/#url

Comment: I'm actually having a problem with the `urlpatterns` definitions being too broad:

the url is valid as long as the core structure is valid, so even something like "/about/shouldnotworkwiththisstring" shows views.about instead of returning 404 error (as it should). 

I think I might but up a separate question for it as it's in a completely different theme and I've been unable to find any comprehensive answers to it yet

Comment: if you use `path('views/productview/<int:product_id>/', views.productview)` or `url('^views/productview/(?P<product_id>\d+)/$', views.productview)` it will match only the integer values after the `views/productview/:int/` and not anything else, so change your `/about/.../` path to match what you actually want.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that your solution had an elusive '$' at the end of it and I decided to try that, and it seems like that works for me in the way I want: if the URL has any extra parameters or strings then the URL is invalid

Comment: It is matter of the other question and not to being solved in comments because is no information about that problem.